# PROLOG -- logic base of entries to LIST of entries

Tags: prolog

In `PROLOG` I have a logic base of entries (which are stored in memory) which I have to convert to a list of entries.

example:

```
| ?- rule(A,B).

A = member(_h209,[_h209|_h212])
B = true;

A = member(_h209,[_h211|_h212])
B = member(_h209,_h212);
```

TO

```
[member(_h209,[_h209|_h212]),true,member(_h209,[_h211|_h212]),member(_h209,_h212);]
```

Can anyone please let me know how can I get it.

Comment: Why do you want to flatten heads and bodies? I cannot imagine when this does make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something close to your expected result (except the semicolon at end) could be:

```
rule_list(Rules) :-
     findall([A, B], rule(A, B), L),
     flatten(L, Rules).
```

A note on _h209, occurring at first position of member: I'm not sure you know the meaning of such symbols. These are **variables**, and if you interested in mantaining the identities these express, my suggestion isn't correct. Use bagof in such case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply @chac .. I basically also want to remove duplicates out of the obtained list. But `setof(L,findall([A, B], rule(A, B), L),Set)` does not work. Can you please help?

Comment: too much nesting... try `setof([A,B], rule(A, B), LPairs),flatten(LPairs,Set)`. or add `sort(Rules,RulesNoDupl)` to posted code